# How to center the caption in a boxed algorithm?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, algorithms, algorithm2e

I want to center the caption in the following algorithm by using the `algorithm2e` package. But I do not get it.

The documentation tells me that `\SetAlgoCaptionLayout{centerline}` should work, but it doesn't.

Do you have any ideas? :)

Thanks a lot!

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \SetAlCapSkip{.5\baselineskip}
  \SetAlgoCaptionLayout{centerline} % Does not work.
  \SetCommentSty{commentFont}
    \newcommand\commentFont[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \KwIn{Some Data\tcp*[r]{This is some input data.}}
  \While(\tcp*[f]{A while-loop}){\(j<\dots\)}{
    Do some stuff.\tcp*[r]{Comment}
    \(j=j+1\)\tcp*[r]{Increment}}
  \KwOut{Output data\tcp*[r]{Some fancy results}}
  \caption{This is a long long very loooooooooooooooooooong caption.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug of `algorithm2e`. From the comment of definition of `\algocf@makecaption` in `algorithm2e.sty`, if caption is shorter than `\hsize`, then it is centered. Hence I remove the `\SetAlgoCaptionLayout{centerline}` from your example.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \SetAlCapSkip{.5\baselineskip}
  \SetCommentSty{commentFont}
    \newcommand\commentFont[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\algocf@makecaption
  {\hbox}
  {\hskip\algomargin\hbox}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \KwIn{Some Data\tcp*[r]{This is some input data.}}
  \While(\tcp*[f]{A while-loop}){\(j<\dots\)}{
    Do some stuff.\tcp*[r]{Comment}
    \(j=j+1\)\tcp*[r]{Increment}}
  \KwOut{Output data\tcp*[r]{Some fancy results}}
  \caption{This is a long long very loooooooooooooooooooong caption.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]